# MATLAB while loop within else statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to run some code similar to that below...I think I'm having a fundamental misunderstanding of for loops. I want to iterate through a for loop, if a condition at each iteration is satisfied (X==True) I want to complete that iteration, if its not satisfied/else I would then like to see if it satisfies a second condition (Z==True)...if it does I would like to continue doing thing2 and counting that as an iteration **while** the condition is true, once it stops being true i would like it to run another for loop doing thing3 5 times, then return to the original if statement for the next iteration.
If the second condition (Z==True) isn't satisfied, I would like it to do that same 5 iteration thing3 for loop. 
Hope that made sense...thanks

```
for i=100:-1:1
    if X==True
        i=i-1;
        do thing1;
    else
        while Z==True
            i=i-1;
            do thing2;
        end
        for n=1:1:5
            i=i-1;
            do thing3;
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified: thing1, thing2 and thing 3 are each adding to a vector...so I would assume my vector would end up with length 100, instead I end up with a much larger vector

Comment: Well, you _will_ end up with longer vector with this loop. __Every time__ `X` is `false`, `while` in your `else` statement will add unspecified amount of items to vector, and inner `for` at least five, so if `X` is `false` at least once, you already have no less than 104 items.

Answer (score 0):

while Z=True is an infinite loop. Do check it.